# Why skip doesn't work at the begining of the aggregation pipeline but works at the end of it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

The skip stage does not work at the beginning of this mongo database aggregation frame work pipeline :

```
[
    {
      $skip: (!offset)?  0 :(offset-1)*limit
    },
    {
      $match: (query)? query : {}
    }
    ,
    {
      $lookup: ...,
    },
    {
      $lookup:..,
    },
    {
      $addFields: {
        userReact: {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            {
              $map: {
                input: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: '$reacts',
                    as: 'react',
                    cond: { $eq: ['$$react.publisher', viewerUserName || ''] },
                  },
                },
                as: 'react',
                in: '$$react.reactType',
              },
            },
            0,
          ],
        }
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        labels: 0,
        comments: 0,
        __v: 0,
        reacts: 0,
        publisher: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        "publishDate": -1
      }
    },

    {
      $limit: limit
    }
  ]
```

but it works when I put it this way

```
[
     <Same stages>
    {
      $skip: (!offset)?  0 :(offset-1)*limit
    },

    {
      $limit: limit
    }
  ]
```

and I want to know what kind of operations affect it. and what the best practices are. is it better to put the skip stage at the top?

Comment: Can you be more specific what "does not work" means? Does it return an error, incorrect results, something else?

Comment: Skip absolutely works, but _what_ it skips is completely dependent on where it is in the pipeline and therefore what the incoming stream of documents that it processes looks like. At the beginning it will skip the first set of 'random' documents read from the collection. At the end of your pipeline it is going to skip the set of filtered and sorted documents. I'm not sure there's a 'best practice' here apart from using keyset pagination instead of skip/limit if possible. Otherwise placement in the pipeline depends 100% on desired business logic

Comment: What I mean by it does not work that it does not work it does not skip any documents

Comment: I just wanted to know on what does it depend .so I don't face this issue again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to implement a kind of pagination, you should always :

1. `$match` according your parameters to filter most documents
2. Do any operations needed for your `$sort` (for example adding a field)
3. `$sort` with the field you want (here `publishDate`) + `_id` field (`{$sort: {"publishDate": -1, id : -1 } },`). The _id part is important to keep consistency in results because 2 docs can have the same value for `publishDate` but won't have same value for `_id`
4. `$skip` now that your docs are sorted
5. `$limit` to keep the number of docs you want
6. Do additionnal thing if you want here (projection, etc)

If you `$skip` before sorting, you'll skip random documents and it will ruin your results.

I made a simple example on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sSmCy2uvaBG). On this example, I want to get all the "lemons" sorted by key, skip one and keep all the rest.

- If i use `$skip` first before `$match`, it will skip the 1st document which is not even a lemon --> WRONG OPTION
- If i use `$skip` after `$match` but before `$sort`, it will skip a lemon but maybe not the one i wanted since it's not sorted yet --> WRONG OPTION (if you change order of document in collection it will change the output)
- If i use `$skip` after `$sort`, i will always get the same results --> GOOD OPTION